# VIES VAT api SOAP error ipv6

Tags: php, soap, ipv6

Here is the server settings/issues I am encountering:

- SOAP is installed and working on the server
- Using PHP SOAP extension ( `new SoapClient(self::VAT_VALIDATION_WSDL_URL)` ) to make the calls
- The WSDL URL I am using is: http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService?wsdl
- Same code is working on most other machines, but not on the current one
- SOAP response is `request_success => bool(false)`, so the request is not made succesfully
- Trying to connect to the url using telnet, for example, results in 503 Internal server error, and from other computers 502 Permission Denied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is hard to trace, but easy to solve.

**ec.europa.eu** accept **IPv6** requests, and responds to them using IPv6. The problem is that not all services are working correctly with IPv6. So if your server works with both IPv4 and IPv6, it will prefer using IPv6, thus the SOAP request will fail.

For example:

```
WKT-03:~$ ping6 ec.europa.eu #not working
connect: Network is unreachable

WKT-03:~$ ping ec.europa.eu #working
PING ec.europa.eu (147.67.136.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

**Solution:**

There are 2 solutions, either to [disable ipv6 on the server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-disable-the-ipv6-protocol.html), or to add a new rule in `/etc/hosts`:

```
147.67.136.103 ec.europa.eu # when/if IP changes, this stops working
```

Thus forcing it to use IPv4. Neither is very elegant, but this should work until the API is fully functional with IPv6.

Answer (score -2):

SoapClient has a `stream_context` option.

1. Create `stream_context` with `bindto` targeting your IPV4 interface
2. Use this context in SoapClient.

Example:

```
$opts = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => 'IP4_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_SERVER:0'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$client = new SoapClient(self::VAT_VALIDATION_WSDL_URL,
    array(
        'stream_context' => $context
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please add further details when you are answering a question so that the OP can solv the problem easier and future visitors can understand it.